# Write multiple records in two column in excel using java

Tags: java, automation, excel-2010

I have two column namely Setup and Request in excel, need to write multiple rows in excel using java

```
public void WriteExcelValues() throws IOException {
String Ustr= setup.getText();
String urequest = request.getText();
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") 
                            + "/src/main/uat/testdata/FreeTestData.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int n = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {   
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i); 
        Cell cell = row.createCell(8);
        Cell cell1 = row.createCell(9);

        cell.setCellValue(Ustr);
        cell1.setCellValue(urequest);
        //cell.setCellValue("AcknowledgementId"); 
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);   
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

for example

[image]

Above code is not complete and doesn't satisfy the criteria also.

Comment: Personally I've never used it, but there is a framework for working with xlxs: https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/

Comment: And the question is…?

Comment: Setup and Request are column name in excel, i have shared the image , how data has to be written in excel

Comment: Why do you create cells 8 and 9 when you obviously want to insert values into the cells 0 and 1? Additionally, you don't close the workbook instance, which may lead to broken files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Setupid");
headerRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Request");

int cellCount = 10;

for (int i = 1; i <= cellCount; i++) {

    Row row = sheet.createRow(i);

    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("cell " + i);
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("cell " + i);
}

File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") 
                            + "/src/main/uat/testdata/FreeTestData.xlsx");

if(file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}

file.createNewFile();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

workbook.write(fos);

fos.close();

workbook.close();
```

Comment: I have write in the existing excel sheet only , what changes have to be done in the above code

Comment: @VipinSingh try
 ```Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

```

Comment: String Ustr= setup.getText();
String urequest = request.getText();                                                                            cell.setCellValue(Ustr);
cell1.setCellValue(urequest);   I have to pass the string value to setCellValue which will be unique or same

Comment: Can u please help in modifying the code using the above requirements-@Coma

Answer (score 0):

I think your for loop is not correct

```
 for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
```

It should be

```
for(int i=1; i<=lastRow; i++){
```